# why is my response.body empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Below is test class. I am getting `response.body as empty` when finding an account.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ProjectController, :type => :controller do
  before(:all) do
    @acc = FactoryGirl.create(:project, name: "test", 
                   description: "Something about test");
    user = User.login(FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "test@test.com", 
                    password: "test", code: 0));
    if user
      @auth = user['auth_token']
    end
  end

  it "can find an account" do 
    Account.find(id: 2055, authorization: @auth);
    hashed_response = {
        "@type" => "test",
        "createdAt" => "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
        "description" => "Something about test",
        "disabled" => false
    }

    expect(response.status).to eq 200    
    expect(response.body).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);

  end

end
```

When i try to `find Account`, it gets me result but why is my `response.body` empty. Below is the response i get in **log/test for Account.find**

```
{
    "@type": "res",
    "createdAt": "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
    "description": "test",
    "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: you didn't perform any request like `get`, `post`, `put`, etc

Comment: Can you show me how to perform get request for the find method with those two params.

Comment: you should include the controller action you want to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Account.find(id: 2055, authorization: @auth)` is going to return an `Account` object, not a response, as it is an ORM request rather than a web request. If you want to test for a web request response, you'll need to make a request first.

I think your test should look something like this:

```
it "can find an account" do
  Account.should_receive(:find, with: {id: 2055, authorization: @auth}

  get :show, id: 2055 # you might need to pass in some auth details also

  hashed_response = {
    "@type" => "test",
    "createdAt" => "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
    "description" => "Something about test",
    "disabled" => false
  }
  expect(response.status).to eq 200    
  expect(response.body).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);

end
```

Comment: How to pass auth details there?

Comment: Also will get :show method return me a json response.